# Replace ng-valid/invalid classes with bootstrap .has-success/error classes

Tags: css, angularjs, validation

guys.

Do you know any good practices to make angularjs add bootstrap (or any different) classes instead of native ones during validation process?

I want to override `ng-valid` with `has-success` without editing `.css` files.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass... you can use ng class

Comment: @h11, so as I understand, `ng-valid/invalid` will be added anyway, but additionaly we will add our own class "manually" corresponding to `$valid, $invalid` and other variables of FormController? No overriding  logic is provided by angularjs?